# Scrapy not recognised command

Tags: python, scrapy

I have successfully installed Scrapy and all it's dependencies into Python.org 64 shell on a Windows Vista 64 bit platform. This is installed as Site Package. I have tested Scrapy works ok at a basic level by typing:

```
Import Scrapy
```

Into a Python Shell and got no errors. I've just got started with tutorials on how to use Scrapy. Most of these suggest setting up a new project using the following Command Prompt line:

```
C:\Python27>scrapy startproject myproject
```

However this throws up the error message in the title about Scrapy being an invalid command. I have tried amending my environment variables to allow me to use this command from any file location within Command Prompt. I have added the following to the end of my environment variables:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapy;C:\Python27\Scrapy
```

This does not seem to resolve the problem however as I still get the same error message. I have also tried running the 'scrapy startproject myproject' command from the following locations with Command Prompt:

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\Python27\Scrapy
```

This again still throws up the same error message. I feel like I am quite close to having the solution, but I just cant quite seem to make it work.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

In response to the last comment above from MattDMo, the command now works, however it now throws up the following error message, which I'm not even sure where to start with:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>scrapy startprogram mrscript
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\reactor.py", line 38, in
<module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 56, in
<module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\default.py", line 50, in
_getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 1
8, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 24, i
n <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 29, in <mod
ule>
    from twisted.internet._newtls import (
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_newtls.py", line 21, in
<module>
    from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\tls.py", line 41, in <mo
dule>
    from OpenSSL.SSL import Error, ZeroReturnError, WantReadError
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 4, in <module>
    binding = Binding()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\bindi
ng.py", line 87, in __init__
    self._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\bindi
ng.py", line 106, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    libraries=libraries,
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\utils.py", li
ne 80, in build_ffi
    extra_link_args=extra_link_args,
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 341, in verify
    lib = self.verifier.load_library()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 75, in load_librar
y
    return self._load_library()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\verifier.py", line 151, in _load_libr
ary
    return self._vengine.load_library()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\vengine_cpy.py", line 138, in load_li
brary
    raise ffiplatform.VerificationError(error)
cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: importing 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\
\cryptography\\_Cryptography_cffi_444d7397xa22f8491.pyd': DLL load failed: The s
pecified module could not be found.
```

Is this actually an error log or just a standard print out? Also, could someone explain please why adding a .bat file to my Python scripts causes this to work?

Thanks

Comment: how did you install scrapy?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974402/python-scrapy-startproject-command-not-recognized

Comment: @AnkushShah i've read that question and this isnt a duplicate as the solution given for that issue does not appear to have resolved my issue.

Comment: For your latest issue, try changing `startprogram` to `startproject`.

Comment: Python on windows becomes janky, yeah thanks DOS. -_- You might have luck using an absolute path and a module call like:
`c:\python27\python.exe -m Scrapy startptoject myproject`

Comment: @ThorSummoner it is recognising the command now, but is throwing up an error because win32openssl is not installed as a dependency (i am told)

Comment: You will have to ask Google for further help, I only know how to make python stuff run on windows, not debug them ^-^

Answer (score 1):

`pip install scrapy` installs a file called **`scrapy`** in Python's `Scripts` directory on Windows, the default location for which is `C:\Python27\Scripts`. However, `C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy` is a Python file, even though it lacks the `.py` suffix. There are two ways of running it. My preferred method is to use the [Git Shell](http://git-scm.com/), as **`scrapy`** has its executable bit set, and can be run without further ado.

The other method, if you want to keep using `cmd.exe`, is to make a batch file with the following contents:

```bat
@echo off
c:\Python27\python c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy %*
```

Save it in the `Scripts` directory as `scrapy.bat` (assuming your `PATH` now includes `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts`), restart `cmd.exe`, and you should now be able to run it from the command line.

Comment: please see the above answer i have posted to my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem (I'm using a virtual environment in Windows 7).

I noticed that for older versions of scrapy, e.g. `pip install scrapy==0.18.4`, it automatically creates a `scrapy.bat` in my virtual environment: `{VENV_ROOT_FOLDER}\Scripts\scrapy.bat`

But if I use the latest scrapy (currently version 0.24.2), the `scrapy.bat` is missing.

I wanted to use the latest scrapy version, so what I did is to put a copy of `scrapy.bat` to its Scripts folder and it solves the problem.